# Python: not sure why I am getting "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" error

Tags: python

I thought it would just be easier to post a slightly modified version of my code (modified for privacy reasons). Essentially I am creating a directory structure based on information given in a csv file. The code starts with converting the csv into a 2d list. Then the script searches through the csv to find the relevant information and row by row should create a directory path. The directory path is to be checked to see if it exists already and if it doesn't then it should be created. The only problem is that my loops used for pi and poc give me an error "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" and I am not sure why.

```
    #We need to find what column in the 2D list these fields are listed in the header
    x,y = index_containing_substring(data,"PiID")
    pi = []
    if x != None and y != None:
        for i in range(len(data)):
            pi[i] = data[i][y]
        #removes header row 
        pi.pop(0)
    else:
        pi = None
        print(' ')
        print("No value for PI")


    x,y = index_containing_substring(data,"RequesterID")
    poc = []
    if x != None and y != None:
        for i in range(len(data)):
            poc[i] = data[i][y]
        #removes header row 
        poc.pop(0)
    else:
        poc = None
        print(' ')
        print("No value for point of contact")
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full traceback for the error and what you may have attempted, so as to make it easier for us to help

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Use `pi.append(data[i][y])` and `poc.append(data[i][y])` if you just concat the entries to an empty list.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/______/_____.py", line 85, in <module>
    filepathgenerator(csvdata)
  File "/______/___.py", line 50, in filepathgenerator
    pi[i] = data[i][y]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Answer (score 2):

For example, here:

```
pi = []
if x != None and y != None:
    for i in range(len(data)):
        pi[i] = data[i][y]
```

You can't assign to non-existent elements of `pi`.

One way to fix this is by using `list.append()` instead:

```
pi = []
if x != None and y != None:
    for i in range(len(data)):
        pi.append(data[i][y])
```

The same pattern appears in a few other places in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this line caused the issue

```
pi[i] = data[i][y]
```

Instead of that use

```
pi.append(data[i][y])
```

See the following link for more information

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html